# JavaScript - cannot find imported file

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to create a JavaScript worker, where I require the [JSONfn](http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/) library. I'm not entirely sure how to import it?

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsonfn.js"></script>

    <script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
        self.onmessage = function f(message){
              console.log(JSONfn.parse(message...)
        }
    ...
    </script>
<html>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: JSONfn is not defined
```

Comment: Did you download [jsonfn.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vkiryukhin/jsonfn/master/jsonfn.js) and put it in the same folder as your `.html` file?

Comment: Yep! I did some testing and I'm able to use the library within the main inline JS script, just not within the worker script block.

Comment: I fail to see how that JSONfn library is even useful. What does it do that the built-in [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) cannot do?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a function into the web worker. JSONfn lets be do this: https://dev.to/localazy/how-to-pass-function-to-web-workers-4ee1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import external scripts in your Web Worker, you can use the [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) method available in non-module Worker contexts.

However, this particular library doesn't seem to be meant for use in a Worker (it calls the `window` getter, which isn't available in Worker contexts). It seems that simply redirecting `window` to `self` does the trick, but it may very well fail in other places.

Also, to parse back from the main thread you'll obviously have to load the library again in that context (through a `<script>`).

```js
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([document.querySelector("[type=worker]").textContent], {type: "text/javascript"}));
const worker = new Worker(worker_url);
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  console.log("received", evt.data);
  const parsed = JSONfn.parse(evt.data);
  console.log(parsed)
  console.log(parsed.baz());
};
```

```html
<script type="worker">
window = self; // jsonfn uses "window"
importScripts("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vkiryukhin/jsonfn/jsonfn.js");
const obj = {foo: "bar", baz: function() { return "blah"; }}
const json = JSONfn.stringify(obj);
postMessage(json);
</script>
<!-- to parse from the main thread we need to load the library here too -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/vkiryukhin/jsonfn/jsonfn.js"></script>
```

Also beware that this library requires that you do declare your function with the `function` keyword (arrow functions or method syntax aren't supported), and that it won't be able to retrieve anything outside of the scope of the function, it really just does copy the source code, nothing about the context.